# VBA Len Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code in VBA:

```
For x = 4 To 3918
    If InStr(Cells(x, 2), "LW") Then
        numToFind = Cells(x, 1)
        For y = 4 To 3918
            If Cells(y, 1) = numToFind Then
                Cells(y, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x
```

However, I am trying to change the condition from "if cell x,2 contains string "LW"" to "if cell x,2 contains 5 characters..." in line 2. I am having trouble properly using the len() function. Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you improperly using it now?  Seeing your attempt can help others diagnose your issue.

Comment: if len(cells(x,2).value)=5 then

Comment: Honest question: Why isn't this just a conditional format??   `=FIND("lw",B1)` for original logic, or `=LEN(B1)>4`  or for your length logic ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Len(Cells(x, 2).value) = 5 Then
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I just made a mistake and had to combine both functions so I said If Len(Cells(x, 2).Value) = 5 And InStr(Cells(x, 2), "LW") Then and it worked great :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`if len(cells(x,2).value)=5` then may as well make it an answer :)

Comment: do we know if we wants exactly 5 characters? or at least 5 characters?  I read "contains 5 characters" as same as "contains LW" .. in other words, it may have other text, as long as it contains what you're looking for .. (ie 5 characters).   so the string "asdfasdfasdf" contains 5 characters. (it happens to contain 12, but it also contains 5, and 6, and 3 ... :) )

Answer (score 0):

Here: `if len(trim(cell( x,2).value)) = 5 then....`